# Is there any tool that gives us a list of verbs often used with a certain word?

Tags: word-choice, resources, dictionary

Is there any tool that gives you a list of verbs often used with a certain word? Sometimes, you forget certain words so you spend time trying to remember and it can be really frustrating at times.

Is there a dictionary or thesaurus that does that? You put a word in there and it gives you a list of verbs you can use.

For example, if you enter door, you get push, open, lock, hold, knock on, and sort them by the order of frequency. It's something that could be really helpful since thesauruses only gives you related words and not words that seem to appear together.

Comment: That would be an interesting tool! It could be probably geared for writers by building it from a corpus of literature.

Comment: Not 100% what you want, but Google might help: you can use * for a missing word in a phrase.

Comment: The problem with Google is that * doesn't work if you're looking for a phrase, and most results are duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be looking for:

- a collocation dictionary (e.g. http://www.freecollocation.com/) which lists [collocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation), that is terms that often occur together.
- a language corpus (e.g. https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) which allows you to search through a large collection of written texts (such as newspaper articles or books) for specific words/phrases and see their immediate context.